# Criteria for abstract polytopes to be convex polytope

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, convex-polytopes, abstract-polytopes

Suppose I have an abstract polytope defined by a poset. Are there any methods for determining whether the abstract polytope can be  geometrically realized as convex-hull on its set of vertices?

Comment: This is called the "Steinitz problem".  See http://www.mathematik.tu-darmstadt.de/~pfetsch/apropo/steinitz_problem.html

Answer (score 2):

You may be interested in this negative result, which shows the space of realizations
of an abstract $4$-polytope may be arbitrarily wild:

---

[image: Universality4Polytopes]

---

Quote from the [*Handbook of Discrete and Computational Geometry*](http://www.crcpress.com/product/isbn/9781584883012), 2nd Edition, p.370.

As the link Hugh Thomas provided indicates, Richter-Gebert also proved that determining whether an abstract polytope is realizable is NP-hard for fixed dimensions $d \ge 4$.

Comment: While Joseph O'Rourke is right that the general case is probably tricky, one can do something in more restrictive settings: For $d=3$ Steinitz' theorem tells you if your abstract graph is actually the graph of a convex $3$-polytope. If this is the case you know that your abstract polytope is realizable. For the $d$-dimensional case there exists Friedman's algorithm that allows you to reconstruct a simple polytope from its graph in polynomial time (based on results by Blind & Mani and Kalai). Maybe this can be used to decide if an abstract simple polytope is realizable.